# Behavior of std::map iterators and insertions

Tags: c++, iterator, time-complexity, stdmap

As a simple start

```
Map<key,val> map1=//filled up in some way;
Map<key,val> map2;
map2.insert(map1.begin(),map1.end());
```

We know that `map::insert` is O(log(n)), with no hint provided. Does this mean that the above runs in O(nlog(n)), or does it use the fact that map1 is already sorted and simply inserts at correct positions (incrementing the current iterator)? Because map1 is already sorted, we should be able to do this in linear time. What about

```
std::copy(map1.begin(),map1.end(),map2.end());
```

Does it insert every time in O(log(n)), or does it copy in O(1) to the respected position marked by incrementing the iterator?

A more illustrative example perhaps

```
template<class InIter, class OutIter, class ResIter>
ResIter foo(InIter first, OutIter last, ResIter res){
   while(first!=last){
      res=*first;
      ++first;
      ++res;
   }
return res;
}
```

Does this run in O(n), or O(nlog(n)), when we are dealing with a map iterator? Are insertions O(log(n)), or are they O(1), because we specify position, i.e. `*res=*first`?

Edit for clarity:

Does

```
*res=*first
```

behave as

```
map2.insert(res,*first)
```

meaning, inserting into map2, using the iterator `res` pointing to the correct position as a hint, making it O(1), or does it perform the regular O(log(n)) insertion?

Comment: Nice question. Note that if you used the actual copy constructor, you'd probably get an efficient copy. The other option is to insert in a loop, using `end()` as the insertion hint, which is always correct if you read the source map in order. (You can do that with `copy` and an insert-iterator.)

Comment: `std::copy(map1.begin(),map1.end(),map2.end());` has undefined behaviour if `map1` is not empty because `map2.end()` is not dereferenceable.

Comment: Is there a way to use hint when inserting via iterators, such as *res=*first ? Ia m asking because this is a toy example, in the real one, its not about copying an entire map. Regarding your comment, I should change it to map2.begin()?

Comment: Inserting ordered data into a balanced binary tree is actually the worse case as the tree has to be rebalanced after each insertion.  If the tree was not rebalanced all nodes would be created down a single branch of the tree.

Comment: But the contents of map1 are already sorted, which is why I claim we should be able to do this in linear time. Perhaps I misunderstood you.

Comment: @LeastSquaresWonderer: I was thinking `copy(src.begin(), src.end(), inserter(dst, dst.end())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick read on standard, there is no requirement on the complexity of `void insert(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);`. So a lazy implementation is allowed to have a O(n log(n)) complexity, even it is likely that it will be linear if `map1` is empty due to what follows.

Because the standard does require a linear complexity for the constructor if the input range is sorted, so this is required to be O(n):

```
Map<key,val> map1=//filled up in some way;
Map<key,val> map2(map1.begin(),map1.end()); // complexity in O(n)
```

For the second part of your question, as you want to give a hint on where the element should be inserted, the correct way would be:

```
template<class InIter, class OutIter, class ResIter>
ResIter foo(InIter first, OutIter last, ResIter res){
   while(first!=last){
      emplace_hint(res, *first);
      ++first;
      ++res;
   }
return res;
}
```

Unfortunately, the standard places no requirement either on the complexity of `emplace` or `emplace_hint`.

Comment: For the first half, I do not need a copy, I made a (perhaps failed) contrived example as a basis for my question. For your second part, please see my Edit for clarity -> as I understand it correctly, this means that the *res=*first does not behave as map2.insert(res,*first), but your emplace_hint does?

Comment: Standard explicitely says that `map2.insert(res, *first)` is equivalent to `return emplace_hint(res, std::forward(*first))`

Comment: Yes. And *res=*first is equivalent to a regular insert? I am sorry for all the follow up questions.

Comment: I could not find any reference for that in standard, but I assume that `*res = *first;` is equivalent too to `map2.insert(res, *first);`

Comment: They moved a lot of stuff to 23.2 (container requirements).  The complexity for `insert(InputIterator first, InputIterator last);` is specified as `a.insert(i, j)` `N log(a.size() + N)` (`N` has the value `distance(i, j)`

Comment: Also the requirements for emplace, emplace_hint, insert with a hint are all in table 102.

Comment: @NathanOliver thank you. Do you know how *res = *first; behaves? Does it behave as map.insert(res,*first), taking res as a hint, as speculated?

Comment: @LeastSquaresWonderer I'm not sure `*res = *first` even compiles.  [It does no here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7eca27f8bc6b95e5)

Comment: @LeastSquaresWonderer Does that compile?  I would think that is also a compiler error.

Comment: @NathanOliver Again, I am sorry, I got confused after your comment. I just looked at the original code. *res=*first; was correct. It compiles with no errors, using g++ -std=c++11

Comment: @NathanOliver OK, reading here [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator/operator*), we see that operator* returns this (does nothing), therefore *res=*first and res=*first are equivalent. Because operator= is overloaded, both compile and perform an insertion. [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator/operator%3D) we see that it takes res as a hint, as speculated. This resolves my question, thank you all :)